# xcode: AppDelegate error when running the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to xcode and I'm trying to create an app which uses an sqlite database to display some data but I get this line of code highlighted in AppDelegate.h when running the simulator.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

I tried a few solutions from similar questions but I couldn't fix it. any suggestions?

Comment: A lot of errors hang up on that line, it's not always a signal that the error is actually there.  Have you checked the error log, at the bottom of the screen, for details about what went wrong?

Comment: @AlexanderWinn thanks for the quick response. this is what it shows me on the bottom: reason: ''UITextField' is not a supported collection class. Expected subclass of NSArray.'

Comment: That is a problem with `IBOutletCollection`s specifically.  You may have assumed that the type of one is supposed to be the type of it's member outlets.  Turns out it's only supposed to be either NSArray or NSMutableArray.  Check your property declarations.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a top level error you see when there is another problem.  Check the console for a more detailed error message.

Alternatively, you can set Xcode to break on exceptions, which will probably help you isolate the source of the error.

http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions